# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock isn't working from Task

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using c# (.aspx).

I have button OnClick callback as follow:

```
protected void btnReplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //Code thats take 30secs to run
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "script", "ShowMessage('Done');", true);
    });
}
```

At this case `ShowMessage` function isn't called, but if i'm change the code as follow:

```
protected void btnReplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code thats take 30secs to run
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "script", "ShowMessage('Done');", true);
    });
}
```

The function `ShowMessage` is called.
Why its happend and How can i fix it? or you can suggest please any another way to execute my code?

Thanks

Comment: You've tried Task.Run()?

Comment: Does my answer solved your issue? Consider marking it as solution if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a task does not make your `btnReplay_Click` method to wait for your task completion.

This means here that your task is not finished **BEFORE** your method returns (and therefore your ScriptManager can't access a page that has already been rendered).

That's why it work on the second version of your code (no more task).

You should try to wrap your long running code [asynchonously](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx) instead, or run it [in background](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) if method end is not crucial for validation done on the client-side.